# MVC Extend Registration Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am wishing to extend the existing Account/Register process that comes as standard with a new MVC project in Visual Studio 2013. Despite editing what I think is required, when I publish the /Account/Register it just redirects to login page.

I have modified the AspNetUsers table to include the following extra fields:

```
[TitleId]       INT            NULL,
[SexId]         INT            NULL,
[Forename]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Surname]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Email]         NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
```

I have amended the registration form to include the new fields.

I have modified ApplicationUser as below:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, TitleId = model.TitleId, Forename = model.Forename, Surname = model.Surname, Email = model.Email };
```

I've updated the RegisterViewModel as below:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string TitleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Forename")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]  
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Despite all these changes, the Register page will not show, simply redirects and I am getting no errors from Visual Studio 2013 re code syntax issues or build errors.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Below is the ActionController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private WebApplication1Entities db = new WebApplication1Entities();

        public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            var userValidator = UserManager.UserValidator as UserValidator<ApplicationUser>;
            userValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
        }

        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Email or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Title()
        {
            var titleModel = from m in db.Titles select m;
            return View(titleModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, TitleId = model.TitleId, Forename = model.Forename, Surname = model.Surname, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
        {
            ManageMessageId? message = null;
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
            }
            else
            {
                message = ManageMessageId.Error;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage
        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
        {
            bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasPassword)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { UserName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LinkLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Account"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LinkLoginCallback
        public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
            }
            var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
        {
            var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
            return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && UserManager != null)
            {
                UserManager.Dispose();
                UserManager = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private bool HasPassword()
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.PasswordHash != null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
            Error
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri) : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: did you update .chtml file?

Comment: Which chtml file are your referring to?

Comment: i think registration.chtml. Check in registration action in account controller.

Comment: Post your entire Action code including all Attributes.

Comment: Which Action Code, I've included everything I need above.

Comment: Your controller action.

Comment: Please see my amended post which shows the ActionController.cs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's expecting the user to be authenticated, when the user is not yet authenticated.  So there could be security here to account for.  Make sure you use `[AllowAnonymous]` to allow an anonymous user into the system.  Or the way it is checking security, it is not checking correctly and thus things your user is unauthenticated.

I don't know all the changes that were made, and what comes out of the box, but that's what it sounds like is happening based on your description.

Comment: I stripped things back a little it turns out it was the TitleId field which was causing the issue, wrong data type for one reason, but I need to a TitleId select field into the form which returns a list of Id's and Titles from the Title table, any ideas?